# Draw wordcloud for each point in scatterplot

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I create a scatterplot which is defined on the following data (note that only first two fields are currently using for plotting):

```
var data = [[5,3,"{'text':'word1',size:4},{'text':'word2','size':1}"], 
            [3,5,"{'text':'word3',size:5},{'text':'word4','size':4}"],
            [1,4,"{'text':'word1',size:3},{'text':'word2','size':5},{'text':'word3','size':2}"],
            [2,3,"{'text':'word2',size:1},{'text':'word3','size':5}"]];
```

Next, when we click on each particular point in the scatterplot the application should attach a wordcloud which is defined from words stored in the 3rd field of the `data` variable. I use Jason Davies's implementation of [wordcloud](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud). Currently (for demo purposes), the wordcloud is generating onlyfrom the static data stored in variable `frequency_list`. The current code is also stored on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akastrin/s6tbtgLe/5/).

Any idea how to proceed?

```
var data = [[5,3,"{'text':'word1',size:4},{'text':'word2','size':1}"], 
            [3,5,"{'text':'word3',size:5},{'text':'word4','size':4}"],
            [1,4,"{'text':'word1',size:3},{'text':'word2','size':5},{'text':'word3','size':2}"],
            [2,3,"{'text':'word2',size:1},{'text':'word3','size':5}"]];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 15, bottom: 60, left: 60},
    width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[0]; })])
  .range([ 0, width ]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
  .range([ height, 0 ]);

var chart = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg:svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr('class', 'chart')

var main = chart.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('class', 'main')   

// Draw the x axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient('bottom');

main.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .attr('class', 'main axis date')
    .call(xAxis);

// draw the y axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient('left');

main.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
    .attr('class', 'main axis date')
    .call(yAxis);

var g = main.append("svg:g"); 

g.selectAll("scatter-dots")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("svg:circle")
  .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return x(d[0]); } )
  .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d[1]); } )
  .attr("r", 5)
  .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "red")})
  .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "black")});

// FUNCTION TO DISPLAY CIRCLE
g.on('mouseover', function(){
  div.style("display", "block")
  d3.select("krog").style("fill", "orange");
  generate();
});

g.on('mouseout', function(){
  //div.style("display", "none")
  div.select("svg").remove();
});

var div = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("display", "none");


// Functions to draw wordcloud
var frequency_list = [{"text":"study","size":40},{"text":"motion","size":15},{"text":"forces","size":10},{"text":"electricity","size":15},{"text":"movement","size":10},{"text":"relation","size":5},{"text":"things","size":10},{"text":"force","size":5},{"text":"ad","size":5}];

var color = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,10,15,20,100])
            .range(["#ddd", "#ccc", "#bbb", "#aaa", "#999", "#888", "#777", "#666", "#555", "#444", "#333", "#222"]);

// Generates wordcloud
function generate(){
  d3.layout.cloud().size([800, 300])
    .words(frequency_list)
    .rotate(0)
    .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
    .on("end", draw)
    .start();
}

function draw(words) {
  d3.select("div").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 850)
    .attr("height", 350)
    .attr("class", "wordcloud")
    .append("g")
    // without the transform, words words would get cutoff to the left and top, they would
    // appear outside of the SVG area
    .attr("transform", "translate(320,200)")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(words)
    .enter().append("text")
    .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
    })
    .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here.

First, your data has strings for the words. I changed that for an array of objects:

```
var data = [[5,3,[{'text':'word1',size:4},{'text':'word2','size':1}]], 
        [3,5,[{'text':'word3',size:5},{'text':'word4','size':4}]],
        [1,4,[{'text':'word1',size:3},{'text':'word2','size':5},{'text':'word3','size':2}]],
        [2,3,[{'text':'word2',size:1},{'text':'word3','size':5}]]];
```

After that, I changed the function `draw`: instead of appending a new div every time you hover a circle, it just change the div content:

```
div.append("svg")
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 300)
    .attr("class", "wordcloud")
    .append("g")
```

But now comes the most important change:

You are displaying the wordcloud every time the user hover a circle, but you're calling the mouseover for the group element. That way, we cannot access the data bound to each specific circle.

Instead of that, we'll set a variable for the circles:

```
var circle = g.selectAll("scatter-dots")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("svg:circle");
```

Thus, we can get the data for each hovered circle, which is the third element in the array:

```
circle.on('mouseover', function(d){
    div.style("display", "block")
    d3.select("krog").style("fill", "orange");
    generate(d[2]);//here, d[2] is the third element in the data array
});
```

And we pass this third element (`d[2]`) to the function `generate` as a parameter named `thisWords`:

```
function generate(thisWords){
    d3.layout.cloud().size([800, 300])
    .words(thisWords)
    .rotate(0)
    .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
    .on("end", draw)
    .start();
}
```

here is your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jwrbps4j/

PS: you'll have to improve the `translate` for that words.