# Combine d3.js with jquery function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

This question is motivated on the basis of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200359/draw-wordcloud-for-each-point-in-scatterplot) on drawing scatterplots and wordcloud. Jason Davies's wordcloud somehow didn't worked for me, so I replaced it with pure jQuery wordcloud - [jQCloud](https://github.com/lucaong/jQCloud).

The aim of the application stays the same. When I go over the point on the scatterplot, the wordcloud should appear. I have two questions:

1. When the page is loaded I should go over the point twice to render the wordcloud. I have no idea why.
2. In current setting the wordcloud won't hide when the `mouseout` event is called. How to repair that?

Any ideas are appreciated. The code is pasted below and also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akastrin/povrp9sk/4/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var data = [[5,3,[{'text':'word1','weight':4},{'text':'word2','weight':10}]], 
            [3,5,[{'text':'word3','weight':5},{'text':'word4','weight':4}]],
            [1,4,[{'text':'word1','weight':3},{'text':'word2','weight':5},{'text':'word3','weight':2}]],
            [2,3,[{'text':'word2','weight':1},{'text':'word3','weight':5}]]];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 15, bottom: 60, left: 60},
    width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[0]; })])
  .range([ 0, width ]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
  .range([ height, 0 ]);

var chart = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg:svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .attr('class', 'chart')

var main = chart.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .attr('class', 'main')   

// Draw the x axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient('bottom');

main.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
  .attr('class', 'main axis date')
  .call(xAxis);

// draw the y axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient('left');

main.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
  .attr('class', 'main axis date')
  .call(yAxis);

var g = main.append("svg:g"); 

var circle = g.selectAll("scatter-dots")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("svg:circle")
  .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return x(d[0]); } )
  .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d[1]); } )
  .attr("r", 5);

// FUNCTION TO DISPLAY WORDCLOUD
circle.on('mouseover', function(d){
  div.style("display", "block")
  $("#my_words").jQCloud('update',d[2]);
});

circle.on('mouseout', function(){
  div.style("display", "none")
  div.select("svg").remove();
});

var div = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .style("display", "none");

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are using an 'update' function of jCloud, which I was unable to find documentation for. If you call 'update' only when cloud is already populated, everything goes fine:

   ```
   var cloudInitialized = false;
   // FUNCTION TO DISPLAY WORDCLOUD
   circle.on('mouseover', function(d){
     d3.selectAll("#my_words span").style("display", "inline");

     if (cloudInitialized)
       $("#my_words").jQCloud("update", d[2]);
     else
       $("#my_words").jQCloud(d[2]);

     cloudInitialized = true;
   });
   ```
2. You are hiding a *different* div in your code (a kind of a tooltip, not wordcloud).

Working example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/povrp9sk/10/